# Boxing Multiple Math Lines when Using the Align Environment

Tags: formatting

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setlength{\mathindent} {0pt} 

\begin{document}

\{(n, l, m_{l}) = {&(2,0,0)\\
&(2,1,-1),(2,1,0),(2,1,1)\\
&(4,2,-2),(4,2,-1),(4,2,0),(4,2,1),(4,2,2)\\
&(4,3,-3),(4,3,-2),(4,3,-1),(4,3,0),(4,3,1),(4,3,2),(4,3,3)\}
\end{align*}$

\end{document}
```

How do you box multiple math lines when using the align environment?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use `framed` environment of the homonymous package, but your formula give an `overfull \hbox`, because it is too long and goes out of the right margin:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt} 
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}
\begin{framed}
\begin{align*}
\{(n, l, m_{l})\} = \{&(2,0,0)\\
&(2,1,-1),(2,1,0),(2,1,1)\\
&(4,2,-2),(4,2,-1),(4,2,0),(4,2,1),(4,2,2)\\
&(4,3,-3),(4,3,-2),(4,3,-1),(4,3,0),(4,3,1),(4,3,2),(4,3,3)\}
\end{align*}
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\boxed` and `aligned`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\setlength{\mathindent} {0pt} 

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\[
\boxed{%
  \begin{aligned}
    \{(n, l, m_{l})\} = \{
    & (2,0,0)\\
    & (2,1,-1),(2,1,0),(2,1,1)\\
    & (4,2,-2),(4,2,-1),(4,2,0),(4,2,1),(4,2,2)\\
    & (4,3,-3),(4,3,-2),(4,3,-1),(4,3,0),\\
    & \quad(4,3,1),(4,3,2),(4,3,3)
    \}
  \end{aligned}
}
\]
\lipsum[2][1-4]

\end{document}
```

I indented the continuation line in order to avoid an overfull box; depending on the text width you set, this might be avoided.

[image]